# Copy directories that have more than 2 files in them

Tags: bash

I have a lot of directories; a lot of them have just 1 file or 2 in them.

I want to copy the directories which have more than 2 files in them in another directory, how can I check it and move the directories?

I have come so far with the script but I'm not sure of it.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir "subset"
for dir in *; do
        #if the file is a directory
        if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
            #count number of files
            count=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l)
            #if count>=2 then move
            if [ "$count" -ge 2 ]; then
                #move dir
                #   ...
            fi
        fi
done
```

The command `mv $dir ..` moves the directory up of one, but is it possible to move up of one and down in `subset` without using complete path `mv $dir complete_path/subset`?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me.  `mv "$dir" toDir` will move directories as well as files.  What happens when you run your script?

Comment: `count` seems working, but I'm not sure it will works if the `toDir` is in the same directory the script is working, and I don't know how the `mv` command of a directory in a parent directory is.

Comment: Your counting of files needs some attention. For the same reason as you should [never parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) you should be careful with `find`. So instead of: `find . -type f | wc -l`
I would use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "A" | wc -c`

Comment: @kvantour (blatant plug ahead) But you can use my [ls0](https://github.com/cxw42/ls0), which exists for precisely that reason :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many traps and pitfalls if you want to handle arbitrary directory names and contents.  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code tries to avoid all of them:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob   # glob patterns that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s dotglob    # glob patterns expand names that start with '.'

destdir='subset'

[[ -d $destdir ]] || mkdir -- "$destdir"

for dir in * ; do
    [[ -L $dir ]] && continue               # Skip symbolic links
    [[ -d $dir ]] || continue               # Skip non-directories
    [[ $dir -ef $destdir ]] && continue     # Skip the destination dir.

    numfiles=$(find "./$dir//." -type f -print | grep -c //)
    (( numfiles > 2 )) && mv -v -- "$dir" "$destdir"
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` means that the code will work if run in an empty directory.  (Otherwise it will try to process a spurious directory entry called '*'.)
- `shopt -s dotglob` enables the code to handle directories whose names begin with '.' (e.g. `.mydir`).
- You could avoid the directory check later in the code by changing the loop guard to `for dir in */ ...`, but that would slightly complicate the check for symbolic links.
- The code assumes that you don't want to move symlinks to directories that contain more than two files (`[[ -L $dir ]] && continue`).  Remove the line if that assumption is not correct.
- Counting the number of files under a directory is tricky because files can have newlines in their names, which means that `find ... | wc -l` might not work correctly.  See [How can I get a count of files in a directory using the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1125/264812).
   The convoluted first argument to `find` (`"./$dir//."`) is designed to avoid several pitfalls.  The quotes prevent special characters in directory names causing problems.  The `./` prefix avoids the argument being treated as an option if the directory name starts with `-`.  The `//.` suffix means that there will be exactly one '//' on a line for every file found by `find`, so `grep -c //` will accurately count the number of files.
- The `--` argument to the `mkdir` and `mv` commands is to ensure that they work correctly if `$dir` or `$destdir` begins with a `-` (which would cause them to be treated as options).  See [Bash Pitfalls #2 (cp $file $target)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I've come so far.

I wanted to know if there is a more elegant solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir "OOOO3_LESS_THAN_TWO"

for dir in *; do
        #if the file is a directory
        if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
            #count number of files
            count=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l)
            #if count<=2 then move
            if [ "$count" -le 2 ]; then
                #move dir
                mv -v "$dir" /completepath/"OOOO3_LESS_THAN_TWO"
            fi
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is fine. There's no clearly superior way to count how many files are in a directory, unfortunately.

You can get rid of the `-d` check by looping over `*/`. The trailing `/` means only directories will match.

You could combine the assignment and test. You may like it or may find it weird looking.

You could also use `((...))` to do arithmetic. I find it a bit more readable, personally.

```
for dir in */; do
    if count=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l) && ((count >= 2)); then
        ...
    fi
done
```

Or you could elide the `count` variable entirely.

```
for dir in */; do
    if (($(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l) >= 2)); then
        ...
    fi
done
```

It's possible to do all of this in a single `find` invocationbut now we're definitely in *arcane* territory.

```
find . -type d \
    -exec bash -c '(($(compgen -G "$1/*" | wc -l) > 2))' bash {} \; \
    -exec mv {} subset/ \;
```

---

> The command `mv $dir ..` moves the directory up of one, but is it possible to move up of one and down in `subset` without using complete path `mv $dir complete_path/subset`?

You haven't change directories so use whatever relative path you like. If I understand the question, it might be as simple as `mv <dir> subset/`.